# How can i get the address of a variable in a class and a variable in a method in that class?

Tags: c++

Here is a sample code.
I want to get address of int K that is in Volume() and also Length. How can i do that?

```
   #include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

class Box {
   public:
     
      Box(double l = 2.0) {
         length = l;
      }
      double Volume() {
         cout<<"Done"<<endl;
         int k=300;
      }
      
   public:
      double length;    
};
      

int main() {
   Box Box1(5);    
   Box *ptrBox;                 
   ptrBox = &Box1;
   cout << "Volume of Box1: " << ptrBox->Volume() << endl;

  
   return 0;
}
```

How can i get the address of a variable in a class and a variable in a method in that class ?

Comment: `int k` is not a class member variable but a local variable (of function `Box::Volume()`). To get its address is possible but very probably the prerequisite for Undefined Behavior. However, to access `Box::length` is quite easy (as you made it `public`): `Box1.length` would do the job as well as `ptrBox->length`. (Didn't you learn this in your C++ book?) And, btw. your function `Box::Volume()` has a non-`void` return type but you didn't `return` anything. (That's Undefined Behavior as well.) Maybe, you intended to `return k;` but forgot to write it down?

Comment: The undefined behavior is because i picked an example code and stripped it to fit my question. I was able to get 'Box1.length' address but i cant find a way to get 'int k' 's address.

Comment: `int k` is a variable with _automatic storage_.  That means its location is chosen every time `Volume()` is called.  And it no longer exists when `Volume()` returns.  At any moment, there may be many instances of that `k`, or there may be none.

Comment: I could show you how to get `int k`s address but I wouldn't do you a favor with this. `k` is a local variable in `Box::Volume()` and its life-time (aka. existence) just ends when the execution returns from the call of `ptrBox->Volume()`. Returning the address of `k` would end up in a dangling pointer which points to nothing which _may_ be accessed. (Hence, I mentioned _Undefined Behavior_ as this is how it is called in C++ if you do something which you can do but you shouldn't do.)

Answer (score 1):

To get the address of any variable:

```
int i;
int * ptr = &i;
```

You already kind of do this. Well, you can also do:

```
double * dPtr = &Box1.volume;
```

It's not any different. It is, however, a really bad idea. You're also successfully getting the address of a variable in the method, but understand that the local variable is going to go away, and it's a really, really bad idea to use it after the method ends.